# Image with imagick driver resizing into small image gives large file size

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, imagick, intervention

I am resizing large images on my project to create thumbnails. Here is one example:

Original Image (1160 x 773):
[image: Original Image (1160 x 773)]

Thumbnail (400 x 266):
[image: Thumbnail (400 x 266)]

The problem is, the large image is 732kb which is I think understandable since it's size is big, but the second image is still 573kb.

Is this normal or is there something wrong?

Here is my code for resizing:

```
\Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($originalPath)
    ->resize($resized_width, $resized_height, function($constraint){
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    })
    ->save($thumbnailPath, 85);
```

Comment: This is normal. Use quality 30 for the thumbnail.

Comment: But wouldn't it produce a blurry image if the quality is 30? Also this is a special case because I've already resized more than a hundred images with the same code and almost the same size but their file size are far more smaller than this one. Most of them are just 70kb when resized to the thumbnail size.

I think I have like 10 images with this situation and I even set already the quality to 0 it was very blurry and pixelated but still the size is not far from 500kb.

Comment: You should add these details to the question.

Comment: Im sorry about that. But then isn't it already strange that when an image is resized more than half its image size the file size is still close to the original one? I just thought the question would have been more simpler that way.

Comment: These images in question, do they come from a different format than the others?

Comment: No, they are a mix of jpeg's and png's. But these mostly happens on jpeg images. And they are uploaded by users so I don't really have much control over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and you will get a small size image with aspect ratio.

```
$configpath = 'Path of destination';
$width      = ($width)?$width:200;
$height     = ($height)?$height:200;
$img = Image::canvas($width, $height);
$image = Image::make($path)->resize($width, $height, function ($c) {
        $c->aspectRatio();
        $c->upsize();
});
// insert resized image centered into background
$img->insert($image, 'center');
$img->save($configpath.$width.'x'.$height.'_'.$filename);
```

Comment: Awesome man! Thanks for your help. I've tried on my local machine and its working correctly. I will try this later on my server and if the output is the same i'll mark this as the correct answer. For future reference I've used gd driver instead of imagick this time.